# How to run a GWT project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I have a mavenized GWT project, which runs perfectly fine with `mvn gwt:run`.

If I import it into Eclipse and try to run as a web application, I get the error `Main type not specified` (see below).

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

What can I do in order to run and debug a GWT application in Eclipse?

**Update 1:** After I specify the main class, I get another error:

[image: Screenshot 3]

**Update 2:** Here's what the `.classpath` file looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/Project1"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/Project2"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/Project3"/>
    [...]
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to debug GWT applications in Eclipse:

1. Run `mvn gwt:debug`
2. Connect to it from Eclipse (as a remote Java application).

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem where the main class is not specified. I have had this problem a few times, the first time I try to run the project.

Go To Run As -> Run Configurations.

You should have a run configuration for your project after you tried running it the first time. In the "Main" tab specify the main class as
"com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode".

This will resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. See my update 1 - now I'm getting another error.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Run > Run Configurations in your Eclipse menu. Select your configuration (most likely, "editor.html").

Click on GWT tab. Make sure that modules are added to the "Available modules".

if this does not help, click on the "Arguments" tab (further to the right from GWT). Make sure that your entry point is listed in the arguments. It should look like this (it's only a fragment of all arguments):

> -codeServerPort 9997 -port 8888 -server
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher
>   com.myCompany.myApp.MyEntryPointClass

Answer (score 1):

> error Main type not specified

The value for Main class is missing in below snapshot.

Simply remove the already created web application configuration.

Now follow the steps that is described [HERE](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/running_and_debugging_2_0) in detail by Google Developers itself.

[image]

---

#### EDIT

It's clear from the error message that classpath contains an entry for `src/main/test` but that folder doesn't exist in the project.

try any one option:

- open `.classpath` file and remove `src/main/test` entries if you don't want to create any test cases.
- create a new folder `test/java` under `src/main` folder.

Comment: Thanks. See my update 1 - now I'm getting another error.

Comment: Regarding `.classpath`: It doesn't contain any `src/main/test` entries (see update 2).

Comment: There is already such folder (`src/test/java`) and it contains some tests.

Comment: OK refresh and clean the project or better to run mavan clean compile command.

Comment: delete all autogenrated files and classes, close the Eclipse and fresh restart might help you or search for `src/test/java` in all type of files using eclipse find tools.

Comment: In maven project it should be under `src/main/test/java`. check pom.xml as well.

Comment: I added an empty directory `src/main/test/java`, but it didn't help.